# Sitecore + Lucene + QueryOccurance.Should not returning desired results

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I Am using Alex Shybas Advanced DatabaseCrawler and it is working beautifully... almost...
I Am using for a carsales application in which you can search for a car using the following values

Model
Make
Fuel
Mileage
Price
Year (Registration date)

I have multiple NumericRange queryies:

1. -1000 - 0                                               (this is for those dealers, that do not want the price online. They write the price as -1)
2. bottom to top ie. (10000 - 20000)            This is what i want to sort by

The are both in the same NumericRangeSearchParam() see code below.
The problem is with the Sitecore.Search.QueryOccurance.Should as it makes lucene completely disregard the price limit. ie

I'll try to illustrate below with the prices returned

Bottom limit: 1000
Top limit: 2000

With Should
   -1,
   500,
   1000,
   25000

With must
   Nothing (as expected)

Should i not be getting only -1 and 1000 with the should occurance?

I Hope one of you can help as this is driving me mad!

Code below:

```
    public List<SkinnyItem> DoSearch(CarSearchParameters parameters, string sortby, bool reverse, string indexName)
    {
        Database db = Sitecore.Context.Database;
        string  id = db.GetItem(SitecoreHelper.GetBilSalgsItem().Paths.FullPath+"/"+ Helpers.URLEncoder.ToFriendlyUrl(parameters.Make) + (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters.Model) ? "/" + Helpers.URLEncoder.ToFriendlyUrl(parameters.Model) : ""), LanguageManager.GetLanguage("da")).ID.ToString();
        var param = new CombinedSearchParam()
        {
            FullTextQuery = "",
            Language = "da",
            LocationIds = id,
            RelatedIds = "",
            ShowAllVersions = false,
            TemplateIds = ""

        };
        Item settings = Helpers.SitecoreHelper.GetSettings();

        Sitecore.SharedSource.Search.Searcher searcher = new Sitecore.SharedSource.Search.Searcher(indexName);
        var items = new List<SkinnyItem>();

        //Tilføjer felter med værdier -Make -Model -Trim
        var fields = new FieldValueSearchParam();
        fields.Refinements.Add("Make", parameters.Make);
        fields.Occurance = Sitecore.Search.QueryOccurance.Must;

        if(parameters.Model != string.Empty)
            fields.Refinements.Add("Model", parameters.Model);
        if(parameters.Fuel != string.Empty)
            fields.Refinements.Add("Fuel", parameters.Fuel);

        //Tilføjer Numeriske ranges
        var km = new NumericRangeSearchParam();
        km.Ranges.Add(new NumericRangeSearchParam.NumericRangeField("KM", 0, parameters.MaxKM));

        //Angivet som must fordi at den skal være mellem disse værdier
        km.Occurance = Sitecore.Search.QueryOccurance.Must; 

        //Tilføjer 2 Ranges da bilen enten skal være mellem det valge range eller mindre end 0
        var price = new NumericRangeSearchParam();
        price.Ranges.Add(new NumericRangeSearchParam.NumericRangeField("Price", -1000, 0));
        price.Ranges.Add(new NumericRangeSearchParam.NumericRangeField("Price", parameters.StartPrice, parameters.EndPrice));

        //Should da den bare skal være en af dem (Svarer til ||, OR)
        price.Occurance = Sitecore.Search.QueryOccurance.Should;

        //Tilføjer datointervallet
        var dates = new DateRangeSearchParam();
        dates.Ranges.Add(new DateRangeSearchParam.DateRangeField("ModelDate", new DateTime(parameters.StartYear, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), new DateTime(parameters.EndYear,12, 31, 23, 59, 59)));
        dates.Occurance = Sitecore.Search.QueryOccurance.Must;

        param.DateRanges.Add(dates);
        param.NumericRanges.Add(price);
        param.NumericRanges.Add(km);
        param.FieldValues.Add(fields);

        //Checker om der er angivet sortering
        if (sortby != null)            
            items.AddRange(searcher.GetItems(param, new Sort(new SortField(sortby, reverse))));
        else
            items.AddRange(searcher.GetItems(param));
        return items;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in the way that Sitecore implements Lucene, which is why my query is behaving this way.

Comment: The only way to prove that is to execute a lucene search directly in the API and compare the results. As most of the Sitecore stuff is a wrapper on top. We use this where we are so I'd be interested to see if you spotted that cos it has implications for us! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it might have to do with the generated boolean logic. I'd drop a breakpoint in the searcher after it has composed its internal lucene query and take a look at the generated query value. Then look at the balancing of the parenthesis to make sure there's not a Must in the wrong place.

You can also use [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) to execute the same queries against the raw index.