# Sitecore Search Ranking

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore6

Does Sitecore/Lucene support filtering/ranking of content?

I cannot find any related documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Lucene returns ranked results, and you can structure queries to filter results using the QueryOccurance.MustNot clause, or to boost results using the QueryOccurance.Should clause.

From Sitecore's [documentation](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Sitecore%20Search%20and%20Indexing.aspx) of the QueryOccurance class:

> Lucene uses the following operators for the search terms in  complex
>   queries:
>    **Must** – the search term must occur in the document to be 
>   included into the search results.
>    **Should** – the search term may occur
>   in the document but  is not necessary, and the document may be
>   included in  search results based on other criteria. However, the 
>   documents containing the search term are ranked higher  than
>   equivalent documents that do not contain the search  term.
>    **Must not**
>   – the search term must not occur in the  document in order to be
>   included in the search results.  Documents with the search term will
>   be excluded from the  results

Some additional resources for Lucene in Sitecore:

- **Syntax of Lucene Queries**: http://sitecoregadgets.blogspot.com/2009/11/working-with-lucene-search-index-in_25.html
- **Lucene Walkthrough**: http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2009/06/LuceneQuery1.aspx
- **Alex Shyba's Lucene posts**: http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/search/label/lucene

This question may also be useful: [Sitecore + Lucene + QueryOccurance.Should not returning desired results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384823/sitecore-lucene-queryoccurance-should-not-returning-desired-results?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore has built-in sitecore_master_content, sitecore_web_content, sitecore_core_content indexes which are indexing all the content in Sitecore and already have an API to search for these indexes. You can specify boosting value in Sitecore "Indexing" item section (by default it's empty).

Also you can set boosting for the fields in your search query.